# Find address of a symbols of a class method using dbghelp

Tags: windbg, dbghelp

I'm trying to use dbghelp in order to find the address of a class method.
For example, a DirectX method (DXGI): dxgi!CDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChainImpl

I've the correct symbols and _NT_SYMBOLS_PATH is defined.
Using WinDBG, the following 'x' command is working fine:

```
0:000> x dxgi!CDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain
6acb78ce          dxgi!CDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain (<no parameter info>)
6acdaf69          dxgi!CDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain (<no parameter info>)
```

However, trying to use this string with SymFromName, I'm getting an error 1168 (Element not found):

```
result = SymFromName( hprocess, L"dxgi!CDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain", &symbol )
// result is false, GetLastError is 1168
```

Does it fail because of the '::', or because there are two addresses for the same symbol (how do I work around?).

Comment: Could you post the complete code you tried? Did you SymInitialize etc etc?

Comment: Also if possible try the Unicode version of API SymFromNameW (Unicode)

Comment: @Rahul, I'm actually using Detour, the method DetourFindFunction, sources are available in the ms-research site (source: module.cpp). SymInitialize is being called within DetourLoadImageHlp. I'm suspicious on the SYMOPT_EXACT_SYMBOL flag. Not sure. Thank you. Regards to everyone on win core sec.

Comment: Thanks for ur wishes :-) And glad ur issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely the SYMOPT_EXACT_SYMBOL setting which is causing the 1168 error to be thrown.  Otherwise having multiple symbols or '::' is fine, and the API can return a valid address.

One work-around would be to use mangled names:

```c
#pragma optimize("", off)
class base
{
public:
    void method(int i)    { printf("in method(int)\n"); }
    void method(double d) { printf("in method(double)\n"); }
};

int __cdecl main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    SymInitialize(hProcess, NULL, TRUE);
    SymSetOptions(SYMOPT_EXACT_SYMBOLS);
    SetLastError(0);

    SYMBOL_INFO symbol = {0};
    symbol.SizeOfStruct = sizeof(symbol);

    BOOL result = SymFromName(hProcess, "cpptest!?method@base@@QEAAXH@Z", &symbol);

    printf("symbol : 0x%I64X\n", symbol.Address);
    printf("error : %u, result : %u\n", GetLastError(), result);

    return 0;
}
```

And for future reference, WinDbg uses the [IDebugSymbols::StartSymbolMatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558815%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to lookup multiple symbols.

Comment: Thank you @Josh. using mangled name indeed fix it. recompiling detour without SYMOPT_EXACT_SYMBOLS also fixes it.